# How to replicate this text effect on Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, font-identification, photoshop-effects

I'm learning how to use Photoshop and I'm trying to achieve this text effect below.

[image: Text Effect image]

First of all I don't know if I need a specific font or if it's possible to start with a "simple" one line font ... I cannot find how to apply a double gradient as well ( maybe with a pattern ?)

Comment: To the downvoter(s): Please add a comment why the downvote. How should one learn without knowing why?

Comment: Where do you see a double gradient? I can only see one: the gold, which can simply done in Photoshop and other software. The inline effect could be two different font weights. The rest is outlines.

Comment: Double gradient is maybe not a good term but there's a break in it for me it : (top) #ecc684 (50%) #ffffff (line break) #f7e5bd (50%) #d29c06 #e9bf6d (bottom)

Comment: @Kurt hover your mouse over the down vote button.... **Down voting is a comment in itself**.

Comment: @Scott perhaps depends of the reputation? I see nothing ...

Comment: @Kurt the hover popup should be there regardless of reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Photoshop cc it's not too hard to replicate.

1. Find a font that is similar like Intro Inline.
2. Add gradient
3. Add one inside thin strokes for the first oultine (#fdf49c)
4. This stroke wont fully fill in the inner line so you'll have to make a new layer and fill with brush.
5. Create warped text and apply arc.
6. Duplicate the Font and place under the last brush layer so it doesn't interfere with previous layer.
7. Add two outside strokes the first Black then a slightly larger white to go behind the black.

This should be a good start.

[image: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-95IdnzJQKfY/Vi1QL-N5lZI/AAAAAAAASOo/ejXlg-LbkbM/w830-h352-no/PERSONA.jpg]

Comment: Thank you so much for the font and the steps, I'll try that !

Comment: It works perfectly ! thank you again ! Instead of step 5 I apply an arc transformation on the layer at the end !